# How do I access a UIPicker in a xib from another class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a `UIPickerView` in a XIB and I have events that modify other elements within this view:

```
- (void) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger) row inComponent: (NSInteger) component {
    [self.definitionBeep play];
   self.glossaryTerm.text = [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:row]objectAtIndex:0];
   self.glossaryDefinition.text = [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:row]objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

I then have another `View`, not built with IB, built programmatically that is accessed from my `ViewController.m` as follows:

```
- (IBAction)someTouchElement:(id)sender{

    if(myWebScroller == nil) {
        myWebScroller = [[MyWebScroller alloc]
                               initWithFrame: CGRectMake(15, mainControl.frame.origin.y, mainControl.frame.size.width, mainControl.frame.size.height)
                               title:@"     MY TITLE"
                               category:myCat];
        [self.view addSubview: myWebScroller];
    }
}
```

Within `MyWebScroller`, I'm listening for clicks and am able successfully intercent them. What I want to do is change the value of the `UIPickerView` and have it change the value of the `glossaryTerms`'s as shown above.

If you need more clarification, please comment and I'll update the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Don't know if I understood correctly, is it not enough to expose the UIPickerView as IBOutlet in controller ? Or mark it with a specific tag, either in IB or at code creation time myPickerView.tag=myCUstomTag, and then later [yourViewContainingPicker viewWithTag:myCustomTag] ?

Comment: The problem is I'm listening for events (within the webview) in `MyWebScroller.m` which isn't part of `ViewController.m`

Comment: uhm, I had a similar problem with an iPad app, when a change on a controller should fire a change in other controller, I ended up launching a custom notification after changing value, and let the other observer controller react to this. If this is your case I can post some code.

Comment: Sure... please post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending what Leonard asked you to do ..

To listen for notification, you need to register an observer for it. so you can do it either in ViewDidLoad: or in ViewWillAppear of Viewcontroller.m

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>   selector:@selector(NotificationPosted:) name:@"ClickedInWebView"
>   object:nil];

then in Viewcontroller.m. implement the method "**Notification Posted**"

> -(void)NotificationPosted:(NSNotification *)notification {
>
> > ```
> > NSLog(@"Something happened");
> > //change the picker here.
> >  }
> > ```

After this, in webView.m, you can post notification whenever you want to change the value in picker view.

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
>   postNotificationName:@"ClickedInWebView" object:nil userInfo:nil]

;

Alternatively, you can also pass the NSString or NSNumber via NSDictionary.

> NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value, @"keyName", nil];
>   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
>   postNotificationName:@"ClickedInWebView" object:nil
>   userInfo:userInfo];

Then you can use this dictionary in viewcontroller in that implemented method. use `notification.userinfo` .